# No instance for `Num (IO ())' arising from the literal `0'

Tags: haskell

I am implementing a simple iterative fibonacci. To test it, I am writing a simple `main`:

```hs
fib n = i where (i, _) = foldl (\(i, j) _ -> (j, i + j)) (0, 1) [1..n] 

main = do
    foldl (\_ n -> print $ fib n) 0 [0, 5, 10]
```

... and getting an error!

```
* No instance for `Num (IO ())' arising from the literal `0'
* In the second argument of `foldl', namely `0'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    foldl (\ _ n -> print $ fib n) 0 [0, 5, 10]
  In the expression: do foldl (\ _ n -> print $ fib n) 0 [0, 5, ....]
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt of using `foldl (\_ n -> print $ fib n)` isn't bad, but it doesn't make sense to initialise this with `0`. Why `0`?

What you're building up here is an action of printing various things. An action is not a number. The "null action" is `pure ()`

```
main = do
    foldl (\_ n -> print $ fib n) (pure ()) [0, 5, 10]
```

This typechecks, doesn't do what you want though: unlike in other languages, `print` does not have a side-effect but needs to be explicitly tied to the `main` action. In this case, you do that accumulatively, starting with `b = pure ()`, then binding the first `print` to it with [`>>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-), etc.

```
main = do
    foldl (\b n -> b >> print (fib n)) (pure ()) [0, 5, 10]
```

...which will indeed print all three results.

A more readable alternative is however

```
main = sequence [print $ fib n | n <- [0, 5, 10]]
```

or

```
main = mapM_ (print . fib) [0, 5, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks, `mapM_` helped a lot

Comment: In such cases I often tend to go full imperative-style and use `for_ [0, 5, 10] $ \i -> do ...`. Especially when the `do` block has to span several lines. (I need to import `for_` unfortunately, but it's not a big deal)